# Calling function with setTimeout with optional way to stop one

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have a function which runs a maths calculation with a callback. I use this function to do calculations for more than one thing by calling it more than once while the previous call may still be processing. (I use setTimeout to do calculations).

The problem is, some times, I need to cancel one of the functions running prematurely.

`For example`... a user clicks an object on a canvas, and the canvas auto zooms in and pans to focus on that object. But the user could mouse wheel to `cancel` the zoom automation, whilst the panning is still going, i hope that made sense and can understand why I might need to cancel one action but not another.

This is my code setup:

```js
var maths = new function() {
  var self = this;

  self.process = function(start, target, duration, callback) {
    var vector = (target - start) / duration;
    var startTime = Date.now();

    function update() {
      start += vector * (Date.now() - startTime);
      startTime = Date.now();

      if (start < target) {
        self.timer = setTimeout(update, 0);
      }
      callback(start);
    }
    update();
  }
};

maths.process(0, 10, 5000, function(value) {
  console.log('Run 1:' + value);
});
maths.process(-5, -1, 5000, function(value) {
  console.log('Run 2: ' + value);
});
```

So i am wondering, how would I be able to obtain a way here to cancel a specific function run when I need to, should I need to.

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out what is a simple way to manage it so it is easy to cancel either call.

Comment: Your code is either incomplete on wrong, can you please create a MCVE to show *exactly* what you're doing, and explain (with reference to this MCVE) what your problem is?

Comment: @Amit http://jsfiddle.net/4pmhy8nn/ works fine here. What do you mean incomplete or wrong ? 

I wish to be able to cancel one or the other but I have no way to interact with them to cancel either one when I need to. I am intentionally not using `setInterval` by the way as i was getting lag issues for my animations.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't notice the `new` in there and thought there was something missing. Can you explain exactly what you want to cancel? I see *Run 1* & *Run 2* alternating console logs, but what do you want to happen?

Comment: @Amit i need some way to identify each run so i can say, assign a button which can then cancel  either run before it even completes. Based on some unique identification. I use a callback to update the numbers, but how can i return a value before hand as an identifier such as `var id = maths.process();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want can be accomplished like this (though honestly, I'm not sure I understood you correctly :-):

```js
var maths = new function() {
  var self = this;

  self.process = function(start, target, duration, callback) {
    var vector = (target - start) / duration;
    var startTime = Date.now();
    var didCancel = false;

    function update() {
      if(didCancel) {
        return;
      }
      start += vector * (Date.now() - startTime);
      startTime = Date.now();

      if (start < target) {
        self.timer = setTimeout(update, 0);
      }
      callback(start);
    }
    update();
    return {cancel: function() {didCancel = true;}};
  }
};

var prc1 = maths.process(0, 10, 5000, function(value) {
  console.log('Run 1:' + value);
});
var prc2 = maths.process(-5, -1, 5000, function(value) {
  console.log('Run 2: ' + value);
});

setTimeout(prc1.cancel, 500);
```

Comment: Ah thanks,  I don't know why I never thought of returning an object